# WP renders HTML wrong when adding widgets

Tags: widgets, html

Here is my code for a footer. Footer element should have div.footer-widgets, nav, and p elements as children. But for some reason wordpress puts everything to div.footer-widget element (I've included the screenshot).

This happens only after adding dynamic_sidebar. What is happening here?

```
<footer class="site-footer">

    <div class="footer-widgets">
        <p>Child1</p>    
        <p>Child2</p>   
        <?php
            if(is_active_sidebar('footer_1'))
            {
                dynamic_sidebar('footer_1');
            }
        ?>
    </div> <!-- End of footer-widget -->

    <nav class="site-nav">
        <?php 
            $arg = array(
                'theme_location' => 'footer',
                'menu_class' => 'navigation'
            );
        ?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
    </nav>

    <p><?php bloginfo('name');?> &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?></p>
</footer>

<?php wp_footer();?>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Also, code for registering a sidebar in functions.php file

```
function our_widget_init() {

    register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=> 'Footer Area 1',
    'id' => 'footer_1',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget' => '</div',
    'before_title' => '<h2>',
    'after_title' => '</h2>'
    ));
 }
add_action('widgets_init', 'our_widget_init');
```

Comment: What's your code for registering the 'footer_1' sidebar?

Comment: Sorry, added it to the end of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing  `>` in the closing div, for `after_widget`:

```
'after_widget' => '</div',
```

Needs to be:

```
'after_widget' => '</div>',
```